WPF spooling/slowing MouseEventHandler events when any key is pressed
WPF UIElement Windows 11 desktop. I've googled for a solution and banged my head on this issue for a few days.  I've noticed a lag in wpf mousemove logic when I had a shift key down to denote different logic. I disabled the shift key logic and saw that simply having any key pressed was impacting the behavior of MouseEventHandler (maybe half as fast, and seems to spool events more.)  Has anyone seen this or know how to keep the MouseEventHandler from spooling and playing events past their time. The issue seems to not exist on a powerful computer, but a low end laptop with UHD seems the worse, though even Iris Xe isn't great.  I have related logic that tracks mousemove without a keypress and it behaves snappy. Any ideas for preventing the spooling mousemove events, optionally worse with a key down, is greatly appreciated. This issue is WPF specific. Similar logic MFC/CPP/DLL, Winforms has no issues. I've tried below.
// key_preview
if (e.IsRepeat && (e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.RightShift))         
    {e.Handled = true;}

// key_down
if (e.IsRepeat == false)
    { doFoo();  e.Handled = true;}
else
    {e.Handled = true;} // force true if anything repeats


You're interacting with the "keyboard" functions. Whether it's via (event) handler(s) or "state" is not evident. And whether or not and how you're dealing with "e.Handled".

I've edited the question.  My key_preview and key_down try to make sure no repeats cause an issue.

You should describe what you're trying to do with the mouse; you make no mention of "which" mouse events you're dealing with. Holding down a key is a form of "mode" (switch). There's more than one way to toggle a mode that doesn't involve holding a key down ... which is a "pain" for some. (I build"one finger" touch apps).

MouseMove. That was my workaround, using a variable to denote alternate logic instead of holding shift.  Not involving the keyboard works snappy.  Holding any key down, seems e.Handled = true is not honored or the _preview event or other key_events seem to induce a performance hit that only shows itself on a medium to low end system, causing mousemove events to spool.  I debug print in various events to see what all is happening and the key preview is the only event that repeatedly shows while holding a key down.  In normal Windows, the WM_MOUSEMOVE message never spools.  key or not.

Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the exact same problem
